# Highcharts Column Group Highlight Dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are trying to address each column group background area by code, in order to display a different color background on hover.

The area we are trying to address is shown here :

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

In the code above the area is described as "Highcharts Crosshair Category" ... which is constantly being redrawn upon mouse move...

Anybody know how to manually trigger this to be highlighted with code?

It doesn't seem that highcharts posses a specific "G" element for the column group stated...

```
Highcharts.charts[0].columns[0].???
```

Comment: Hi @levi, Do you want to achieve the result like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/12ok6Lcy/ ?

Comment: @ppotaczek Yes you should write this in an answer and I should credit this, its exactly what I was looking for... the term crosshair is a bit confusing :)

Comment: Great! I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a crosshair dynamically, you can use internal `drawCrosshair` method:

```
chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair({}, chart.series[0].points[1]);
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/12ok6Lcy/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this effect while using the `column.point.events.mouseOver` [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.point.events), like that:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    pointPadding: 0.2,
    borderWidth: 0,
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          // console.log(this); // To view all params available
          if (this.index < 2){
            this.series.chart.xAxis[0].update({
              crosshair: {
                color: '#5090cc'
              }
            });
          } else if (this.index < 7){
            this.series.chart.xAxis[0].update({
              crosshair: {
                color: '#f0c680'
              }
            });
          } else {
            this.series.chart.xAxis[0].update({
              crosshair: {
                color: '#90d8a2'
              }
            });
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/txu62vL7/)

Comment: That's a good answer, if you can explain how to do this after setting up the chart (not on runtime), it would be the correct answer.

Comment: I don't see anyway to do it before rendering the chart.